# Output of formula as cells for Excel's Indirect()

Tags: vba, excel, excel-indirect

I'm using the `INDIRECT()` function to dynamically refer to worksheets. It seems to me that the function requires a known cell address as input of the formula in quotation marks. However, since I don't know the cell address in advance, I would like to input a cell address that is an output of another formula (e.g., `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX(MATCH())` ). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can compose the string required by INDIRECT() by concatenating formulas that return values that look like a cell address or parts of a cell address.

For example, if your Vlookup or your Index/Match formula returns "A1", then you can use that like

```
=Indirect(Vlookup(this,there,2,false))
```

Or, if one formula returns "A" and the other formula returns "1", then combine the output of the two formulas with the & sign.

```
=Indirect(Vlookup(columnLookup,Table,2,false)&Vlookup(RowLookup,Table,2,false))
```